# cube shape in Latex Math

Tags: symbols, amsmath, shapes

I am looking to define a variable with the subscript indicating it is defined in plane or space, as shown in the attached image. \square works for plane. is there a way to get the cube?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The [Comprehensive List](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) suggests that you maybe could use `\mancube` provided by the `manfnt` package ... But it probably does not work out of the box inside math mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `fontawesome` package has the symbol `\faCube`, which must be used in text-mode (not math mode):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome,amsmath}

\begin{document}

$f_{\text{\faCube}}$

\end{document}
```

Another option (suggested by @JasperHabicht in the comments is to use `manfnt`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{manfnt,amsmath}

\begin{document}

$f_{\text{\mancube}}$

\end{document}
```

Neither is exactly the symbol you pictured. If you want, you can build a symbol from scratch using Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Nice suggestion `+1`

Comment: Thanks a lot! These options will work for me.

Comment: @KumarArumugam: It may seem strange, but on this site, we don't offer thanks in the comments. Instead, you should [upvote helpful answers and accept the one you find most helpful](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).